# What happens to Keychain when iPhone is restored from backup?

Tags: ios, security, persistence, keychain

If you take a backup of iOS **Device A** and restore **Device B** from the backup of **Device A**, will you also get the data from Keychain in **Device A** restored? or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the keychain items have been stored on Device A.
Each app can decide if it's items will be restored to any device, or to the original device only.
See [Key Chain Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html):

> The second dimension of item accessibility determines whether the item migrates to a new device when a backup is restored. If the item’s kSecAttrAccessible attributes ends with the string ThisDeviceOnly, the item is restored to the same device that created a backup, but it is not migrated to a new device when restoring another device’s backup data.

Comment: Thank you, you answer was of great help!